# Why am I seeing an extra folder in my source code?

Tags: web, web-development-server, web-developer-toolbar

I uploaded a repository on github , and used netlify to deploy my website. But apart from the source code I see one node-modules folder, 2 js files that are NOT present in my repository , under a folder , in pages in sources. How to get rid of those? The folder named "Kritika" is unnecessary.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QU6n.png)

What I tried -
reuploaded repository and redeployed. Nothing worked.